# Blender acting as if shift is held down

Tags: shortcut

I'll go to orbit with trackpad and it'll work but then i'll go to do it 10 seconds later and it'll pan instead of orbit, as if shift is being held. It seems to switch on and off for no reason.

It also happens when I <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  to save, it triggers *Save As*.

If I click multiple objects it'll select each of them together, not one or the other.

It only happens in blender, shift isn't being held or effecting any typing or other programs.

Using 2.82.